# Inserting objects into the array till the specified count in iphone and then pushing it out for later additions

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to fill the array with the objects till the specified count and when that count is reached ,I will not add the objects to the array and I am able to do that..

But what I am want is suppose I have given count 7,and & objects are added into the array,so when I want to add the 8th object the object and index 0 should be pushed out and all the objects should be take their their new positions to make place for new object.

So friends how can this be done

from the below comments I tried this code

```
if(count ==7)
    {
    [array1 removelastObject] ;
    }

   [array1 insertObject:orderGroup atIndex:0 ] ;
```

and It works...

Thank you very much friends..

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(id)popAndPush:(id)newObject{
    id poppedObject = nil;
    if([array count]==maxCount){       /// remove first object (new count will be maxCount-1
        poppedObject = [[array removeObjectAtIndex:0] retain];
    }
    [array addObject:newObject];       /// push new object
    return [poppedObject autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I think you may have wanted to only surround the remove with the if max check.  Seems like you always want to add.

Comment: thanks, edited. The initial block was meant only for when maxCount was reached.

Comment: hey babbidi what if i am inserting objects atIndex:0,your logic will fail right?

Comment: if you want to insert at 0 you'd have cal `[array removeObjectAtIndex:maxCount-1]` instead of `[array removeObjectAtIndex:0]` and `[array insertObject:newObject atIndex:0]` instead of `[array addObject:newObject]`.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you want is a circular buffer.  Queues that are implemented over arrays are typically implemented this way - the only difference is a Queue resizes, it sounds like you want to dequeue when it's full so you're retain the most recent X number of items.  As you add & remove items, you do *not* want to shift everything order n - instead, you just keep redefining what the front and back is.

A circular buffer is implement with an array of a certain size and you have two index variables - head and tail.  You also maintain a variable for the count of items.

When you remove an item from the front, you remove the item and increment the head indexer.  When you add an item to the back, you increment the tail indexer and add.  In both cases, when you increment, it can wrap around.  You can either do a check - if index is at last cell, set to 0, or you can use a modulus operation.  index = index % [array count].

Comment: BTW, I believe NSMutableArray is implemented under the covers as a circular buffer so remove and add should be fine.  In hindsight, should have skipped the detailed explanation and just said remove/add like others.

Comment: Here's a circular buffer impl using NSMutableArray: http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/CHDataStructures/interface_c_h_circular_buffer.html

Answer (score 0):

Like so. `array` is an `NSMutableArray`

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:0]; // All of your other objects will move down an index
[array addObject:myNewObject]; // This will be added to the end of your array
```